# Условие "все кроме"

Tags: sql, база-данных, oracle, plsql

В секции "where ..." селекта у меня имеется условие:

```
and FIELD_1 = decode(parameter_1, 1, 11, not 11)
```

Логически оно должно звучать так:
"... и значения FIELD_1 = если paremeter_1 = 1, то 11, а если paremeter_1 не равно 1, то все значения FIELD_1, кроме 11"

Not 11 в моем случае не работает.

Как дополнить мое условие для нужного мне логического соответствия?

Comment: "_а если VALUE_2 не равно 1, то все, кроме 11_" - как это понять? Если `VALUE_2` не равно 1, то чему должно быть равно `VALUE` в итоге?

Comment: Хм. А чем вопрос до правки отличается от вопроса после правки?

Comment: `and decode(parameter_1, 1, (FIELD_1 = 11), (FIELD_1 <> 11))` не проверял

Answer (score 1):

С `decode` так сделать нельзя. Но можно же просто обычное условие написать:

```
and ((paremeter_1 = 1 and FIELD_1 = 11) or (paremeter_1 <> 1 and FIELD_1 <> 11))
```

Comment: Проблема в том, что VALUE_2 в моем случае - входной параметр функции, а VALUE - значения столбца, прошу прощения что не уточнил.

Comment: @n0n4m3 Тогда вопрос переформулируйте. С таким уточнением вообще ничего не понятно.

Comment: @n0n4m3 Ну вот, исправил ответ. Хотя в чем была разница с первой версией вопроса, я не уловил. Может, ее просто нет?

Comment: К сожалению, не понимаю, как изложить понятнее:
"выдай мне значения столбца FIELD_1 = 11, если входной параметр parameter_1 = 1, и выдай все остальные значения, если он не равен 1."

Comment: @n0n4m3 Так запрос-то работает в итоге или нет? Если вместо вашего условия подставить моё.

Comment: вообще работает, сейчас проверю, насколько правильно.

Comment: @n0n4m3 Вообще говоря, если это запрос внутри функции, то неважно, поле у вас там или параметр - работать будет и так и так. Проблемы начнутся, когда названия параметров начнут совпадать с названиями столбцов, но это тоже решаемая проблема.

Answer (score 0):

```
--бред конечно, попробуйте
-- т.е. если FIELD_1=11, то общий итог FALSE, в других случаях TRUE
and FIELD_1 = decode(parameter_1, 1, 11, DECODE(FIELD_1, 11, FIELD_1+1, FIELD_1))
```

Объяснение решения.

**про секцию WHERE**: в секции WHERE определяются выражения типа (boolean), которые будут применимы к каждой записи выборки и в случае, если выражение FALSE, запись в результат выборки не попадет...

**про Условие "все кроме"**: что должно означать? Честно говоря, я не понял, почему задача называется именно так? но из текста, вроде бы, выходят следующие условия:

- Если `parameter_1=1 AND FIELD_1 = 11`, то `TRUE` и запись возвращаем
- Если `parameter_1 <> 1 AND FIELD_1 = 11`, то `FALSE` и запись не возвращаем
- Если `parameter_1 <> 1 AND FIELD_1 <> 11`, то `TRUE` и запись возвращаем

Если я понял текст задачи правильно то думаю мой ответ должен подойти...

**По-моему**: условие "все кроме" - бред, если вам нужно вернуть в запросе все записи кроме определенных, то подходит условие просто кроме:
`AND FIELD_1 NOT IN (a_exept_col)` - где a_exept_col может быть выборкой или вложенной выборкой

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/234557)

Comment: а можете уточнить почему? возможно я не понял вопрос... но вроде является

Comment: Дополните и оформите свой ответ, сделайте его более развернутым.